# Trouble binding to repeater through ajax call

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, jquery

I have a user control that contains a repeater, which in turn is nested in a default.aspx. When a user clicks a specific link on the page, the ajax post function is called which posts data to a method on default.aspx. All good so far! This method then calls a method within the user control, passing in the data, which in turn is used to requery, and rebind the repeater.

For some reason, the page bails when I try to do this last part?

If this seems converluted, it's because it doesn't seem possible in jquery to directly access user control methods.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebinding a repeater control, which is an ASP.NET server control, is done on the server side, not the client side. If you want some grid behavior with ajax I suggest you look at a javascript based grid like for example [**jqGrid**](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The jquery ajax fires a server side method which binds the repeater. So the binding is done within the code behind page.

Comment: So it binds the repeater and transfers back the rendered html of the repeater control? If so then simply in the success part use the html() functionality to inject the rendered html into your page.

Comment: No problem. But you only bind on the server. You also need to get that bound repeater, and rendered one, back to the client via ajax right? If you only bind on the server and don't give back something that your ajax call can inject into the html which stays unchanged (no postback) you don't have anything to inject and view.

Comment: Sorry for beign thick. I don't quite follow. It basically looks like this where getTradeRoutes is an IQueryable list of routes: repTradeRoutes.DataSource = GetTradeRoutes(); repTradeRoutes.DataBind(); - But execution ends before this bind takes place.

Comment: `Execution ends before bind takes place`. Does that mean you get an exception while trying to perform some action? Or what's the reason for that?

Comment: Not quite. The debugger simply stops at the DataSource line, and returns back to the webpage? But there is no exception.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. Because it's not a postback, server binding wont work, and so the query data needs to be passed back to the ajax success - via json? Then format the data clientside.

Comment: You can indeed best return json, though html's also possible. Json however is raw data and you can use a templating engine like the one from Microsoft or jqGrid (or something similar as there are many) to format that data.